# Trying to install oracle database on docker image. Pc freezes

Tags: oracle, docker

I am trying to build oracle database 12c r1 docker image. At some point the pc freezes and doesn't do anything. Even mouse not moving.
I am using virtual box installed ubuntu 18.04. host machine windows 10
Here freezes[image]

Answer (score 0):

reviewing your print screen I've noticed that you have 2 problems to solve for this installation:

1 - increase your /tmp size - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400138/how-to-increase-tmp-folder-size-manually/400140

2- increase your SWAP partition size or create a swap file - https://linuxize.com/post/create-a-linux-swap-file/

Comment: I did it but still the same result